# How to perform Code coverage in Protractor BDD Cucumber Typescript Chai

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, bdd, chai

I have to perform the Code coverage analysis for my project which was built in **Protractor Cucumber using typescript and Chai**. I have referred in google, but it shows for Mocha/Jasmine/Javascript only. Would there be any best tool to do the code coverage for this requirement. Share your ideas and suggestions with some light.

Comment: Check out this [SonarTS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/plugin-version-matrix/)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the Typescript code coverage

**Steps:**

1. Install the following package through npm or yarn with the below command. *typescript-coverage-report* can be installed using the below commands

   yarn add --dev typescript-coverage-report
   (or)
   npm install --save-dev typescript-coverage-report
2. In the JSON file, add the below commands under the scripts section

   "scripts": {
   "ts-coverage": "typescript-coverage-report"
   }
3. To execute the code coverage for typescript use the below yarn or npm command for execution

   yarn ts-coverage

   (or)

   npm run ts-coverage

**Typescript Code coverage report**

[image]

**Useful links:**

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-coverage-report
2. https://github.com/alexcanessa/typescript-coverage-report